# When is a set defined by multivariate polynomial inequalities convex?

Tags: polynomials, inequalities, real-algebraic-geometry

Consider the set of real numbers given by

$$S = \{(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) \in [0,1]^8 : 0 \le \frac{e(g-h)}{b(g-f)} \le 1 \text{ and } 0 \le \frac{e(h-f)}{(1-b)(g-f)} \le 1\}$$

Note that this set can also be defined as

$$S = \{(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h) \in [0,1]^8 : g \ge h \ge f \text{ and }e(g-h) - b(g-f) < 0 \text{ and } eg-eh-bg +bf \le 0\}$$

I'd like to show that there is a unique projection from any element of the 8 dimensional hypercube $[0,1]^8$ onto $S$. My understanding is that one requirement for this is convexity. But how do we show $S$ is convex when it is defined by multivariate polynomial inequalities? Moreover, might there be a faster way to show that there is a unique projection onto $S$ (or that there is not)? Thank you.

Comment: Where does this set come from?

Answer (score 3):

Your set $S$ is not convex. E.g., the octuples $x:=(0, 5/64, 0, 0, 1, 1/2, 1, 1)$ and $y:=(0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)$ are in $S$, but $(x+y)/2$ is not: both conditions $e(g-h)-b(g-f)<0$ and $eg-eh-bg+bf\le0$ fail to hold for the octuple $(x+y)/2$.

---

As for the unique projection, for its existence you will first of all need to replace $S$ by its closure, say $\bar S$ -- which latter will also be non-convex, by what was noted above. So, by the Bunt--Motzkin theorem [Theorem E.9.0.0.1 on page 607](https://convexoptimization.com/TOOLS/0976401304.pdf), the projection here will not be unique.